# Best approach to create a customized page

Tags: pages, full-site-editing

I'm at the beginning of recreation of a WordPress website that:

1. Has 15 informative pages (not posts)
2. A dynamically updated examination index, that refreshes nightly via cron.
3. Serves visitors in three languages: English, Spanish, and Portuguese (all pages).

Since the site displays terrible performance issues, it needs to get rebuilt.

My questions:

- Since the site mostly consists of landing pages, the only way I found to create customized pages, was via custom templates. The downside of the custom templates is that they can't be searched by the website's search engine.
- Or maybe now, with FSE, I can create custom patterns and reuse them. This way, the content will be indexed.

What is your opinion regarding a website that consists mostly of customized pages? How will you deliver that? Using custom templates, or another solution (that will be able to get searched?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason custom templates would not be searchable is if they stored significant amounts of content in postmeta fields, instead of the main content field.

To have customizable layouts whose contents are still fully indexable by default WP search, use the Block Editor. You can create custom blocks if needed, but even the Core blocks and perhaps a plugin or two with additional ones if needed will get you a lot of control over layout and presentation. As long as all the blocks store their data directly to post content (which is the norm - it's infrequent to find blocks that store to postmeta) all that content will be searchable.

And yes, custom patterns will also be stored in content, so will also be searchable and are a great way to store reusable content.